# xor of elements of a list/tuple

Tags: python, xor

I have a tuple of `'0'` and `'1'`, and I want the xor of all its element. For example, if I have `('0', '1', '1', '0')`, I want to obtain `((0 xor 1) xor 1) xor 0`.

I have the following (working) snippet:

```
bit = ('0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0')
out = bit[0]
for i in range(1, len(bit)):
    out = int(out) ^ int(bit[i])
print str(out)
```

How can I make it in a more pythonic way (using `map` and a lambda function ?)

Comment: Why the extra `xor 1` in the example? You had `0, 1, 1`. The results should be `0 xor 1 xor 1`

Comment: The title of this is confusing as XOR is not distributive.  E.g. with your def XOR(1,1,1) is True, but I think most people would expect otherwise.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
print reduce(lambda i, j: int(i) ^ int(j), bit)
```

> reduce(...) reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value
>
> Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
>       from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
>       For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
>       ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).  If initial is present, it is placed before the items
>       of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
>       sequence is empty.

Comment: Seems great. Can you explain a little please ?

Comment: try `help(reduce)` in python shell

Comment: Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value. For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).  If initial is present, it is placed before the items of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the sequence is empty.

Comment: `reduce` must be imported first: `from functools import reduce`

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3 you can use:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import xor
>>> bits = ('0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0')
>>> reduce(xor, map(int, bits))
1
```

Or if you want a *running* XOR:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> from operator import xor
>>> bits = ('0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0')
>>> list(accumulate(map(int, bits), xor))
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, `reduce` works well. If you read about `reduce`, you will come across the concept of a [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) which is a higher order function (like `map`).

In some languages you can fold left or right. Interestingly in your case, you would get the same result if you started from the left or the right as `xor` is commutative and associative.

Answer (score 1):

Kidly take a look at this version is if you are looking for a solution without using reduce or lambda
function

```py
A = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5]
x = 0
for i in A:
    x ^= i

print(x)
```

```
output : 3
```